# installing mechanize on VPS

Tags: ruby, mechanize

> root@cowboomer:/home/ryan/public_html# gem install mechanize -V GET
>   http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz 302 Moved Temporarily GET
>   http://production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz 304 Not Modified
>   GET http://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz 302 Moved Temporarily GET
>   http://production.s3.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz 304 Not Modified
>   Installing gem unf_ext-0.0.5
>   Building native extensions.  This could take a while...

and then it doesn't do anything else. It never actually installs mechanize. Same thing happens for capybara.

Comment: How long have you waited for native extensions to build? "This could take a while...", and sometimes it does :)

Comment: Urm, it just stops and prompts me for the next command. Anyway, I left the terminal running (while I do my stuff) for hours and it doesn't work.